# How to tell cleveref to use the correct label type

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, labels, cleveref

I'm trying to use cleveref to reference some figures, but it is incorrectly labelling them as sections. (i.e. It will say something like Section 5.12 instead of Figure 5.1 in the text)

I'm also using hyperref to make the links, which might be confusing cleveref?

My code looks something like this:

```
\usepackage[pdftex,letterpaper=true,pagebackref=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
% A bunch of hopefully unrelated stuff in between

Some text here \Cref{fig:first,fig:second,fig:third}.

\begin{figure}\label{fig:first}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{./figures/first.png}
\caption{First Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\label{fig:second}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{./figures/second.png}
\caption{Second Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\label{fig:third}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{./figures/third.png}
\caption{Third Caption}
\end{figure}
```

Any idea what could be causing the problem? Alternatively, is there to use just hyperref to reference multiple figures at once? What I want to be able to do is have a reference that looks like: Figures 5.1-5.4 but I couldn't find a way to do that with just hyperref, so I tried using cleveref, and instead it is giving me Sections 5.12 to 5.12 for the same set of labels.

Comment: Put the \label behind the caption.

Comment: This is one of the commonest errors for beginners: don't worry, everybody has to learn.

Comment: Well, that was easy, thanks! I had tried putting the labels in a bunch of different places and it still wouldn't work, but I guess I only built the pdf once for each place I tried. Moving them after the caption and then building the pdf twice did the trick.